# Cambiar opacidad de diferentes doughnut al pasar el ratón por el doughnut principal

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Buenas!!
Soy nueva en programación y necesito que alguien me eche una mano por favor.

Estoy haciendo unos gráficos con Chart.js.
Tengo hecho un gráfico doughnut grande y al lado unos cuantos pequeños. El grande tiene varias áreas de diferentes colores y tengo que hacer que al pasar el ratón por cada una de las áreas, se pinte un doughnut nuevo y los pequeños que tiene al lado tengan opacidad y se queden casi invisibles, menos el que es del mismo color que el gráfico principal. Al quitar el ratón todo volvería a su estado normal. No tengo incluido el css

Por ejemplo: si pasas el ratón por el color rojo el doughnut que se va a mostrar tenga una parte en rojo (según el porcentaje de los datos) y otra en gris (esta parte solo rellenaría la parte que queda).

He conseguido que al pasar el ratón por el doughnut cambie su aspecto (color y datos) pero sin tener en cuenta cada área, sin que los gráficos pequeños se vuelvan opacos y el gráfico no vuelve a su estado inicial.
Alguien sabe como podría hacer esto? Por que a mi no se me ocurre nada.
Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda.

Dejo una foto de como tendría que quedar [image: aquí]

Y aquí dejo mi código:

```js
var ctxMini = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini,{
    type: 'doughnut',
        data : {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 25, 75 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 25 },{  y: 75 }],

                 backgroundColor: ['#fd3f4a','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini2 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area2').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini2,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 48, 52 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 48 },{  y: 52 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#5cc600','#ebe9e1'],
           }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini3 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area3').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini3,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#705bc9','#ebe9e1'],
           }],
        },
         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini4 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area4').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini4,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 12, 88 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 12 },{  y: 88 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#ff8f00','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini5 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area5').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini5,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 8, 92 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 8 },{  y: 92 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#00c9d8','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini6 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area6').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini6,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#484848','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini7 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area7').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini7,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#ffd939','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});

var ctxMini8 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area8').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini8,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#008ee5','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        },

         options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * 0.5,

            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },

            hover: {
                  mode: null
            },
       }
});


var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasDoughnut').getContext('2d');
var backgroundColors = ['#fd3f4a','#484848','#705bc9','#008ee5','#00c9d8','#5cc600','#ffd939','#ff8f00'];
var varData = [25, 18, 18, 18, 8, 48, 18, 12];
var newColors = ['#fd3f4a','#484848','#705bc9','#008ee5','#00c9d8','#5cc600','#ffd939','#ff8f00'];
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        responsive: false,
       
        data: {
             datasets: [{                  
                   backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
                   data: varData                                  
            }]
        },

      
       options: { 
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
            rotation: Math.PI * -0.7,
            events: ['mousemove'],

             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
       
            onHover: function(evt, elements) {
                  var datasetIndex;
                  var dataset;
                  
                  if (elements.length) {
                    var index = elements[0]._index;
                    datasetIndex = elements[0]._datasetIndex;

                    // Reset old state
                    dataset = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
                    dataset.backgroundColor = backgroundColors.slice();

                    dataset.backgroundColor = ['#5cc600'];
                    
                    chart.update();
                  }                                          
            },                                   
       },
});
```

```css
.canvasDoughnut{
  width: 40%;
}
.miniDoughnut{
  width: 50%;
}

.miniDoughnuts canvas{
width: 70px !important;
height: 70px !important;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<div class="canvasDoughnut"><canvas id="canvasDoughnut"></canvas></div>

<div class="miniDoughnuts">
<canvas id="mini-chart-area"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area2"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area3"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area4"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area5"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area6"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area7"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area8"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Ianrs. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿No es la misma pregunta que [la que hiciste antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125011/cambiar-color-y-data-de-un-doughnut-pasando-el-rat%C3%B3n-por-encima-de-cada-%C3%A1rea-del)? Un saludo

Comment: Hola lois6b, no es la misma pregunta, puede que no me haya explicado bien. Aquí lo que pregunto es como ponerles opacidad a los gráficos pequeños al pasar el ratón por el grande. Debería poner las dos en la misma publicación ya que se trata de los mismos gráficos? Un saludo

Comment: Puede que en la misma este bien.. mira [ask] para mejorarla ya que tienes que explicar lo que has intentado y por que ha fallado (errores, resultado no esperado..). Un saludo